# How to identify Application associated with a IP without DPI

Tags: ip, netflow

I am getting a netflow traffic feed, I need to identify the application associated with the IP.
Is there any kind of global database that I can use map the global IP with the application it is used to serve?
Ex: IP A for Amazon Prime
    IP B for Amazon WebService
    IP C for Amazon Shopping

All IP A,B and C are owned by Amazon.

Answer (score 0):

There is no public DB that has that info in that I am aware of. AS number gets you close, but not the detail on which exact service it is contacting. There maybe a way to build a list based on additional netflow intel, like proto or port. If you do discover a more detailed list or wanted to create one manually or part automated, you could create a TrafficGroup for group of IP's you have id'd. Here is the view I get on my home network with Amazon ASN filter
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/4AN2Q.png)